# SQL querying a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database has several columns, some with numerical data.
I want to select specific columns and combine them like a single column.
Then I want to select the top 3 numbers from this based on count.

```
-----------------------------
  PCM  |  M4  |  DS  |  VR1  
-----------------------------
  45   |  34  |  22  |  117
  34   |  201 |  7   |  393
  1    |  117 |  73  |  7
  45   |  55  |  7   |  43
```

So I would select columns `PC`, `M4`, `DS`, `VR1` and return:

```
------------------
 col | col_count
------------------
  7  |     3
  45 |     2
  34 |     2
```

If possible I would like to get the count(frequency) in a single SQL query. If not two would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my post with a data table. I also appreciated that. I tried to but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 col
     , COUNT(col)
FROM (
    SELECT PCM AS col FROM tbl
     UNION ALL
    SELECT M4 FROM tbl
     UNION ALL
    SELECT DS FROM tbl
     UNION ALL
    SELECT VR1 FROM tbl ) t
GROUP BY col
ORDER BY COUNT(col) DESC
```